# ParallelTable does not evaluate DLL functions

Tags: parallelization, librarylink

I have a function programed in C which I load in MMA with

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
MYlTNC = DefineDLLFunction["ltnc", path, "double", {"double", "double", "double", "double", "double"}]
```

It works nicely except when I want to use it within a `ParallelTable` command. It is as if its definition does not get sent to the kernels. Here is a short example:

```
t2 = MYlTNC[0.025, 10, 1.1, 1.1 + 5, 1.1];
Export["try.dat", t2]
FilePrint["try.dat"]
```

outputs the following string correctly

```
3.09128
```

but

```
ParallelTable[
  t2 = MYlTNC[0.025, 10, 1.1, 6.1, 1.1];
  Export["try.dat", t2],
  {10}];
FilePrint["try.dat"]
```

outputs the string

```
If[NETLink`DLL`Private`checkArgCount["ltnc", {0.025, 10, 1.1, 6.1, 1.1}, 5], Wolfram`NETLink`DynamicDLLNamespace`DLLWrapper5`ltnc[0.025, 10, 1.1, 1.1 + 5, 1.1], $Failed]
```

If I replace `ParallelTable` with `Table`, it works fine again.

Is there a way to incorporate within the kernels the definition of the attached DLL?

Comment: Does it help if you evaluate `ParallelEvaluate[
 MYlTNC = DefineDLLFunction["ltnc", path, 
   "double", {"double", "double", "double", "double", "double"}]
 ]` before the `ParallelTable`?

Comment: And also ``ParallelNeeds["NETLink`"]`` before that.

Comment: No, although the output has slighly changed to ```Wolfram`NETLink`DynamicDLLNamespace`DLLWrapper5`ltnc[0.025, 10, 1.1, 6.1, 1.1]```.

Comment: It seems that a sequence of ```LaunchKernels[]```
```ParallelNeeds["NETLink`"]DistributeDefinitions[path, MYlTNC]``` ```ParallelEvaluate[
 MYlTNC = DefineDLLFunction["ltnc", path, 
   "double", {"double", "double", "double", "double", "double"}]]``` does it. Any reason for that?

Comment: Well, apparently, the subkernels were lacking some important piece of information. Without ``ParallelNeeds["NETLink`"]``, they do not know the  framework behind `DefineDLLFunction`. `ParallelTable` can auto-distribute symbols that appear in its body. But apparently, the symbols must be explicit. Moreover `ParallelEvaluate` makes sure that the DLL is loaded into each subkernel. Otherwise, each subkernel might request the main kernel to evaluate this function each time ot appears which would defeat the purpose of parallelization.

Comment: Because of auto-distribition by `ParallelTable`, `DistributeDefinitions[path, MYlTNC]` _should_ be obsolete nowadays, but who know?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: do you want to turn your comments into a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently, the subkernels were lacking some important piece of information. ParallelTable can auto-distribute symbols that appear in its body, but the symbols must be explicit. `` "NETLink`" `` contains many other symbols onto which `DefineDLLFunction` references. In addition, `` "NETLink`" `` might have to load also a couule of library functions. Running

```
ParallelNeeds["NETLink`"]
```

guarantees that this package is loaded correctly on each subkernel. If a not so recent version of *Mathematica* is used, it might be necessary to execute also

```
DistributeDefinitions[path, MYlTNC]
```

in order to tell each kernel from where to read the DLLs. (IIRC, this is obsolete with *Mathematica* newer than 11.x.)

Afterwards,

```
ParallelEvaluate[MYlTNC = DefineDLLFunction["ltnc", path, "double", {"double",   "double", "double", "double", "double"}]]
```

loads the DLL into each subkernel separately. If you do not execute this, each subkernel might request the main kernel to evaluate this function each time it appears. This would defeat the purpose of parallelization.